# Need to make junit tests for a java code which check if a number is power of other number

Tags: java, testing, junit, tdd, junit4

I'm a beginner at JUnit testing and I have some questions about testing. My Java code is about: check if a number(integer) is power of other number(integer), and return boolean True/False. Only one method named isPower(int x,int y) which calculate if (x % y) == 0 ,this is the short presentation of my code.

I want to know what kind of tests I should make on this Java code if returns only true or false, and I should make setup() and teardown() functions?

Comment: `(x % y) == 0` will only test if `x` is a multiple of `y`, not a power of `y`.

Comment: If you really are trying to determine if `x` is a power of `y` (which isn't what `x%y` does), make sure to test cases where `y==1`, both where `x==1` and `x!=1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for `setup()` and `teardown()` because there should be nothing to setup. Usually those are used when setting up some environment like database, service, etc. In your case you would probably have one class with one (static) method.

Usual practice is to test edge cases, i.e. negative numbers, 0, max numbers and let your test clearly document via test code what you expect to happen. Lets say your test should not throw exceptions on any input because you are dividing and not multiplying. Try `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE` for each and for both.

Some unit testing frameworks can generate random data as input for your test so they would test all edge cases.

A little example:

```
@Test
public void test_nominator_nonzero_denominator_zero() {
   MyClass mathObject = new MyClass();
   assertFalse("0 can't be a divisor of a non-zero number", mathObject.isPower(5, 0));
}
```

You question sounds like a description of a function that finds divisor or factor of X.

Comment: So can i do something like this:
 `public void test1(){
  assertEquals(true, Power.isPower(8, 2));
 }`

Comment: of course, and just add each test separately for all types of scenarios that you can think of.